# Angular - use a component as both a pop up component and regular component

Tags: angular, popup, angular-material

Is it possible to have a single component as both a Popup Component and a Regular component?

Because there will be a need to add in the constructor declaring this component as a pop up component

```
constructor(
     private dialogRef: MatDialogRef,
     @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
) {}
```

Something like that.
So if the value is `null` for the  `@Inject`, the inject has to have some value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the @Optional for the dependencies injection. So that it also allows null values in the constructor.

```
constructor( @Optional() private dialogRef: MatDialogRef, @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public IrId: any) {}
```

Comment: The values will be `undefined` and not `null`, but otherwise it means the same.